# Can't store txt file data in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am following an article about image caption transformer model in tensor flow python. When I try to run the following code it does not show the data when I use the head function.

```
file = open(dir_Flickr_text,'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()

datatxt = []
  for line in text.split('\n'):
    col = line.split('\t')
    if len(col) == 1:
     continue
    w = col[0].split("#")
    datatxt.append(w + [col[1].lower()])



data = pd.DataFrame(datatxt,columns["filename","index","caption"])

data = data.reindex(columns =. ['index','filename','caption'])  
data = data[data.filename !='2258277193_586949ec62.jpg.1']
uni_filenames = np.unique(data.filename.values)

data.head()
```

After running this I see three columns (index, filename , caption) with no data at all. While the real file contains enough data and the in the article they display the data too.

Comment: Please post syntactically correct code so that helpers can copy-paste and run your code.

Comment: The complete code is lengthy that's why I am posting a part of it. Am I allowed to share article link in comment? But I am sure there is some problem in this part that's why my data is not showing. I have stored my txt file path in 'dir_Flickr_text' variable, The path is correct when I print dir_Flickr_text variable.

Comment: For starters, fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't show any data because the dataframe is empty, probably because datatext is empty.  Try using a print() statement before data=pd.DataFrame(...  to see what is going on.
It is hard for us to debug without the dataset.

Comment: I really don't know what exactly happened with the dataframe here. I am sharing the article link where all code is present inlcuding this part. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/01/implementation-of-attention-mechanism-for-caption-generation-on-transformers-using-tensorflow/

Comment: You are true that the dataframe is empty. I tried printing dataframe before data=pd.Dataframe...its empty